# Parallel scraping Reddit data

Tags: r, json, parallel-processing

I'm trying to scrape some data from Reddit and just an lapply is too slow but I'm really struggling to parallelize the function.

I don't know how to pull the full json so the data is here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/science/about/moderators.json

```
library(jsonlite)
library(parallel)

dat <- fromJSON(".../mods.txt")

mods <- dat$data$children$name

mod_activity <- data.frame()
author <- data.frame()

mod_list <- function(user) {
use_list <- tryCatch(fromJSON(paste0("https://www.reddit.com/user/", user,".json")),  error=function(e) NULL)

mod_activity <<- rbind(mod_activity,use_list$data$children$data$created_utc[1])
author <<- rbind(author,use_list$data$children$data$author[1])
}

cluster <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)

clusterEvalQ(cluster, library(jsonlite))
clusterExport(cluster,c("mod_list","mods","mod_activity","author"))
parLapply(cluster,mods, function(user) mod_list(user))

stopCluster(cluster)
```

It's not a reproducible example, I know, but it's the closest I can get.

I'm aiming to have a column of author names and their last active date but to NULL any users that have been deleted and return a 403 error.